# Finds an empty folder. But it finds the last one in the list

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is a list of **spisok** Each item in the list is a path to a certain folder.

We need to find the first empty (less than **1 mb**) folder and write the path to it to **itog** variable, but it has to be placed after it in **spisok** list is followed by a folder of size **100mb** or more.

Tried **Nodejs 18** package get-folder-size and **getFolderSize** function but it didn't work.

Using **Nodejs 18**. Implementing folder size determination using the built-in fs tools.
But in variable **itog** I get just the last folder from the the list **spisok**, it weighs **41 mb**...not eligible for the condition of being less than **1 mb** and after it in the list should be a folder over **100 mb** which also does not work because after it no items in the list **spisok** .

**Code:**

```
// Step 1
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const spisok = spisok;


// Declare variables
let pytkpystoypapke = ""; // path to found folder with size less than 1000000 bytes
let itog = ""; // path to found folder will be saved in this variable

// Loop through all folders in list "spisok"
for (let i = 0; i < spisok.length; i++) {
  let folderSize = fs.statSync(spisok[i]).size; // get size of current folder
  if (folderSize < 1000000) { // check if size is less than 1000000 bytes
    if (i < spisok.length - 1) { // check if there is another folder in list "spisok"
      let nextFolderSize = fs.statSync(spisok[i + 1]).size; // get size of next folder
      if (nextFolderSize > 1000000) { // check if next folder size is greater than 1000000 bytes
        pytkpystoypapke = spisok[i]; // save path to current folder in "pytkpystoypapke"
        break; // exit the loop
      }
    } else {
      pytkpystoypapke = spisok[i]; // save path to current folder in "pytkpystoypapke"
      break; // exit the loop
    }
  }
}

itog = pytkpystoypapke; // save path to found folder in "itog" variable


// Output result
console.log(itog);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own. Here is the finished code, maybe it will be useful to someone:

```js
// Declare the list "spisok"
let spisok = [[SPISOK]];
const fs = require('fs');


// Use a for loop to go through all elements of the list "spisok"
for (let i = 0; i < spisok.length; i++) {

    let folderPath = spisok[i]; // Assign each value of the loop to the variable "folderPath"

    //console.log(folderPath); // Print the value of "folderPath" in the log



    // шаг 1. начитаем получать размер папки путь к ней лежит в folderPath
    function getFolderSize(path) {
    let totalSize = 0;
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const stats = fs.statSync(path + '//' + files[i]);
    if (stats.isFile()) {
    totalSize += stats.size;
    }
    else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
    totalSize += getFolderSize(path + '//' + files[i]);
    }
    }
    return totalSize;
    }
    const folderSize = getFolderSize(folderPath);
    // закончили получать размер папки "folderPath" 
    // и размер записали в "folderSize"




    if (folderSize < 1000000); {

        // шаг 2. получаем размер папки лежащей ниже
            let nextElement = spisok[i + 1];
            function getFolderSize(path) {
            let totalSize = 0;
            const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            const stats = fs.statSync(path + '//' + files[i]);
            if (stats.isFile()) {
            totalSize += stats.size;
            }
            else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            totalSize += getFolderSize(path + '//' + files[i]);
            }
            }
            return totalSize;
            }
            const nextFolderSize = getFolderSize(nextElement);
  
        // закончили получать размер папки лежащей ниже и запись
        // записали размер в "nextFolderSize"

        if (nextFolderSize > 100000000) {
             console.log(folderPath);
             //console.log(folderSize);
             //console.log(folderPath);
             [[PYT_K_PROSHLOY_PYSTOY_PAPKE]] = folderPath;
             break
}
}
}
```